# How to get this solution in terms of Modified Bessel function?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I have tried to solve a PDE by using Laplace-Carson transformation and obtained the following solution in Laplace-Carson domain. Is it possible to put the solution in the following Modified-Bessel function?

I got this solution:

$$ y = r^β (C_1 (J_\nu(- i s r)) + C_2 (Y_\nu(- i s r)))$$

I want to reach a form like this solution.

$$ y = ((2)^{1 - β}/\Gamma\left(β\right)) (s r)^β (K_\nu( s r))$$

Knowing that:

$$Y(0) = 1$$

$$Y(Infinity) = 0$$

Comment: Is $\nu$ an integer?

Comment: No .. it is a real variable,